# Database Creation before Insertion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have an android application in which I am using Content Provider on top of the database. However, I see that database gets created only when I insert the first record in the database through the Insert of Content Provider. In this scenario, if there's an error in database creation that would remain pending till the insertion of a record.

I would like to know if there's a way I can create the database when the app is accessed for the first time, so, any possible errors in the database creation appear at the earlier stage.

Comment: did you try saving an arbitrary item right at the very beginning?

Comment: You can deploy your DB as Asset with the app.

Answer (score 1):

Within our app we show a splash screen specifically for the purpose of creating the db and initialising some application singletons. I'd recommend something similar.

You can start a db (on)Create or db (on)Upgrade by calling `SQLiteDatabase#getWritableDatabase` or equivalent. Remember to perform this on a background thread and use standard eventing / callbacks to understand when this (synchronous) method has completed.

If something goes wrong then you can catch that exception during start-up although you can't really recover by the sounds of it so you'll be best off not catching any exceptions and making sure your critical init code is bullet proof.